# Abbreviating long R output in knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

I remember that I've seen a hook in `knitr` to abbreviate `R` output. But I forgot how to accomplish this task. How can I show first few lines and last few lines of `R` output connected with `ellipses (...)`.

```
   \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}

    << Test >>=
    1:1000
    @
    \end{document}
```

I found this [link](http://blogs.baylor.edu/alex_beaujean/2013/05/28/selective-lines-of-output-for-knitr-22/) but it does not work for me.

**Edited**

@kohske solution is excellent and works fine if there is only one output. Need more generalization for such Chunk.

```
<< label=Test, results = "hold" >>=
1:1000
args(lm)
@
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
oh <- knit_hooks$get("output")
knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
  ret <- strsplit(x, "\n")[[1]]
  ret <- paste0(ret[1], "\n...\n", ret[length(ret)])
  oh(ret, options)
})
@


<< Test>>=
1:1000
@
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
  ret <- strsplit(x, "\n")[[1]]
  ret <- if (length(ret) > 2)
    paste0(ret[1], "\n...\n", ret[length(ret)])
  else
    ret
  oh(ret, options)
})
```

Comment: (+1): Thanks @kohske for your help. Your code works fine if there is only one output. This hook more generalization for `results="hold"` and more output per chunk.

Comment: This is probably not because of `hold` but the output of `1:10` has only one line. I fixed it. see the update.